# Angular changedetection ngFor with primeng OverlayComponent

Tags: angular

I am making an Angular application and everything seems to work good.
But I am questioning the performance.

So I tried to implement changedetectionStrategy.OnPush.

I used a tooltip and overlaypanel from primeng
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/overlaypanel

Every click in this list, triggers the getTooltip event. This is certainly not needed. The click event fires changedetection changes.

```
<div #actualTarget
     *ngFor="let event of day.TimeEvents"
     class="event"
     pTooltip="{{getTooltip(event)}}"
     tooltipPosition="bottom"
     showDelay="200"
     (click)="openOverlay(op, $event, actualTarget)">
```

I tried to run the click command outside with ngZone with a custom directive, but this does not show the overlayPanel as it does not trigger the changedetection
https://medium.com/@krzysztof.grzybek89/how-runoutsideangular-might-reduce-change-detection-calls-in-your-app-6b4dab6e374d

Can it be easaly solved, so that the overlaypanel shows, but the tooltip method is not getting called for every div element again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not a change detection but a function call inside template.
It will be called more than once  `pTooltip="{{getTooltip(event)}}"`. Probably better to move the method to pipe `pTooltip="{{event | getTooltip}}"`

You can fin out more [here](https://dzone.com/articles/why-we-shound-not-use-function-inside-angular-temp)

Comment: I'll try that , thanks. What about [ngClass] on the div element? this will also trigger every time a click event is clicked

Comment: Maybe this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56335963/ngclass-calls-method-multiple-times/56337564 will help. Or simply use [class] binding if possible without calling function in template